# WebDriver can not find the element with HotMail https

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a auto sending mail throw hotmail with webdriver 2. 
I'm using WebDriver, with java and eclipse.  
I'm curreently succeed to get in hotmail by login, and i got the main mail page.  
Now i have to click the "New" button (image number 1), 
And when i click it by the command : driver.findElement(By.id("NewMessage")).click(); 
It's working and the page moving to the next compose page (Image number 2). 
But WebDriver thinks he still at the previous page from some reason. 
I can't click on any element on this page. 
 
 
[image: Image number 1]

[image: IMage number 2]

My target is to send keys to the "To" field, but i can't get it.
As you can see in image number 2, I tried to get the element by the "InputBox" class, the id, by className, xpath, etc.
 
I will be happy if someone can help me..  
Thanks, 
Or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `To` field is in the `iframe`. In selenium if you want to do any action in a frame mean first you have to get in to the frame.

**Code to enter the frame:**

```
  //Assume driver is initialized properly  
  driver.switchToFrame("Frame Name");
```

(Or)

```
  driver.switchTo.frame("FrameIndexValue");
```

(Or)

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorValue));  
  driver.switchTo.frame(element);
  //Do any action inside the frame
```

After you finished the action inside the frame you have to get out of the frame to do any action outside the frame.

**Code to Leave Frame:**

```
//driver.switchTo.defaultContent();
```

If you are dealing with the `iframe` then the defaultContent() will take you to the main page above all the iframes, but if you deal with the `frame` this method will take you to the first frame of the page.

For more [info on frmae handling](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.ca/2012/04/frames-and-webdriver.html).